# Where is the iPhone app EULA displayed for the user?

Tags: ios, eula

I am planning to submit an iPhone app for certain special purpose calculations. I want to add a legal disclaimer about the calculations somewhere so that the user can see it atleast once before starting to use the app. Should this go into the EULA that may be submitted as part of app submission process? Or should that be a one time screen shown when the app is started first time? What is the right way?
Thanks for responses.

Answer (score 20):

The EULA would be submitted as part of your delivery to the App Store, so as to be displayed alongside the app’s entry in the Store (so the user can read prior to purchase).

But you’d also be well-advised to display the very same language the first time the app is launched, prompting the user to “Accept”.  (Ideally, if it’s more than one page, you can make it so the Accept button is disabled until the user scrolls to the bottom of the text.)

If you want to be even more thorough, you could prompt the user to accept the EULA the first TWO times the app is run, just to be safe.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why did someone downvote this? It is correct. The EULA is submitted as part of the submission process through iTunes Connect. The user can view it on the App Store via iTunes or the App Store app on the iPhone. It is completely up to the developer of the app whether or not they think the EULA should be shown when the App starts or not, but the EULA should be made available in the app in some way, at least, whether its via a link to a website containing it or it being embedded in the app.

Comment: Thank you, Jasarien!  You’re correct, this wasn’t supposed to be legal advice -- it was an unstated assumption that legal matters should be referred to qualified professionals, and this wasn’t intended to be a substitute for that.  My answer was a practical one of implementation, and which touched on specifics of the attendant user-interface design.  So, thanks for your vote of confidence.  I hope others find these ideas helpful as well.

Comment: Upvoted! ;) Followup question: What is a good practice to follow when you have your own EULA, for DIFFERENT COUNTRIES, and you are required (by the client) to show it in-app? Show 'em all in one long list? Assume an auto-selection based on l10n? (ehhhh.) Make them choose? (Ugh.) Suggestions/BPs welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Show it first time the app is shown, or if it isn't crucial, add a mention in the app description.